# Payara Micro - Hot redeploy doesn't work in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, payara, hot-reload, payara-micro

I've just switched to Payara Micro platform from Glassfish and everything looks fine so far except non-working hot redeployment. Even compile on save option doesn't work, so in order to get my changes applied I have to:

1. Stop Payara Micro instance
2. Manually push "Build" button
3. Start instance again

What is really tedious.

Is there a way to enable a hot redeploy? Or at least to get my code compiled on save so I can skip the step #2?

I'm using NetBeans 14 and Payara Micro 5.2022.3. A "Hot Deploy" checkbox on the "Payara Micro" tab in the settings is checked as well as a "Compile on save" one and others indicated on this page https://blog.payara.fish/hot-deploy-feature-in-payara-platform-5.201

[image]

When I try to re-run the app after making the changes there is the following message in the logs:

```
--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-cli) @ my-app ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
```

So I have to re-build the app manually.

Comment: Tried with NetBeans 12.6, it didn't work as well. Even excessive "Always perform build before running application" option doesn't help. So it looks like a Payara Micro plugin bug...

Comment: Off topic, but to whoever absurdly voted to close this question without comment because it is _"Not about programming or software development"_, please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) This question is very much about  _"software development"_, clearly relates to _"software tools commonly used by programmers"_, and is _"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_.

Comment: [1] What version of Java are you using? [2] Since everything works if you manually do a build, it looks like the problem may be with compile on save not being effective rather than anything to do with the Payara plugin, right?

Comment: @skomisa probably yes, because when I change the file, there is a message in the status section "my-app deployed", so probably plugin was trying to re-deploy it, but there was nothing new to apply. I tried both on 1.8 an 11.

Comment: I've submitted the issue in regard to it but it doesn't seem that it will be fixed in the nearest future.